Is that possible to get the connection between activity and xml layout by parsing the apk?
Per my understanding the apk is a collection of the jvm code file, something like class, dex.
Then We can get the activity name from those class file.
Is that possible to get connection between xml and activity, I know some cases there will be multi layout for one activity, like fragment, etc. But our use case some inaccurate may be also feasible.
In theory, I think can go into the .class to get the static resource.
Not sure if that is possible, anyone ever did similar work before?
Thanks

as of my knowledge xml file are converted to R.java and compiled , so you can get the code there.

I can parse the R.java, but how can I build the relationship between Activity and the layout class in R.java

i don't think you can reverse engineer xml from java , although if the code was written in compose you can get the layout. Sometimes the layout elements are connected to activity file with the id  , so you can track the layout from there.

Layout files are loaded at run-time. Just search for the load commands where the XML layouts are loaded and check into which activity or fragment of an activity the layout is loaded into.
